# Actions with a list of instances - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

what is the best way to do an action with many instances at the same time?

Lets say I have 50 movieclip instances called A1 to A50, and I want to run an action with only A20 to A35.

For example:

```
(A20-A35).gotoAndStop(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an algorithm operation called **loop**. You are not able to abstractly address things in bunches **at once**, but you can loop and iterate the bunch one by one which produces basically the same result. Please read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow#Loops When you need to do a quantity of similar operations it is always **loop**.

With regard to your problem:

```
// Loop iterator from 20 to 35 inclusive.
for (var i:int = 20; i <= 35; i++)
{
    trace("");

    // Compose the name of the MovieClip to retrieve.
    var aName:String = "A" + i;

    trace("Retrieving the MovieClip by name", aName);

    // Retrieve the instance by its instance name.
    var aChild:DisplayObject = getChildByName(aName);

    // Sanity checks about what exactly did you find by that name.
    if (aChild == null)
    {
        // Report the essence of the failure.
        trace("Child", aName, "is not found.");

        // Nothing to do here anymore, go for the next i.
        continue;
    }
    else if (aChild is MovieClip)
    {
        // Everything is fine.
    }
    else
    {
        // Report the essence of the failure.
        trace("Child", aName, "is not a MovieClip");

        // Nothing to do here anymore, go for the next i.
        continue;
    }

    // Type-casting: tell the compiler that the child is actually
    // a MovieClip because DisplayObject doesn't have gotoAndStop(...)
    // method so you will get a compile-time error even if you are
    // sure the actual object is a valid MovieClip and definitely has
    // the said method. Compile-time errors save us a lot of pain
    // we would get from run-rime errors otherwise, so treasure it.
    var aClip:MovieClip = aChild as MovieClip;

    trace(aClip, "is a MovieClip and has", aClip.totalFrames, "frames.");

    if (aClip.totalFrames < 2)
    {
        // Nothing to do here anymore, go for the next i.
        continue;
    }

    // Now you can work with it.
    aClip.gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Now that you understand the while idea step by step, if you are sure all of them are present and all of them are **MovieClip**s you can go for a shorter version:

```
for (var i:int = 20; i <= 35; i++)
{
    (getChildByName("A" + i) as MovieClip).gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

**UPD**: You can as well address children with square bracket access operator.

```
for (var i:int = 20; i <= 35; i++)
{
    // You can skip type-casting as this["A" + i] returns an untyped reference.
    this["A" + i].gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Yet there are differences and complications. Method **getChildByName(...)** always returns a **DisplayObject** with the given name (or null if none found). Square brackets operator returns an untyped OOP field of the current object.

It will not work with dynamically added children (unless you pass their references to the respective fields).

It will not work if "Automatically Declare Stage Instances" publish option is off.

Finally, **this["A" + 1]** and **A1** are not exactly the same because the latter could refer to a local method variable rather than object member.

I'm not saying that square brackets are evil, they're as fine, yet, as always, programming is not a magick thus **understanding what you are doing** is the key.

Comment: This is very helpfull! Thank you!